# Text Detection and Document Text Detection (OCR) - Different results with the same file (Local vs Cloud)

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm having a problem with the new version of Vision API Text Detection and Document Text Detection (OCR). Version that will become default from February 19, 2024.

I am using the same project and the same file but in different locations.

When I run it locally I get one result (the correct one), but when I run it on an Azure VM I get the result with some differences (the wrong one).

I didn't find anything in the documentation about any environment configuration influencing the result.

I'm using ImageAnnotatorClient/AnnotateImageRequest.

```
Builder builder = Feature.newBuilder();
builder.setModel("builtin/latest");
builder.setType(typeDetect); (Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION or Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
Feature feat = builder.build();
```

When I use the current builtin/stable (default) version, I don't have these problems.

The errors are as follows:

Local(Correct): -1.898,37  
VM(Wrong): -1.898**.**37

Local(Correct): 2.340,772   24.703,952    30  
VM(Wrong): 2.340,772    24.703,952    **w**

Local(Correct): 2.290,092   23.857,148    31 
WM(Wrong): 2.290,092    23.857,148    **w**

I tried the following solutions which didn't work:

1. Send "Hints".
2. Set the type as DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION
3. "Process only in the USA"